# JQuery Mobile: Randomly Sort Checkboxes Except One

Tags: sorting, jquery-mobile, random, checkbox

In a survey, I need to show several checkboxes displayed in a randomly fashion, but one of them have to be still, since I need to capture a text for example

```
What is your favorite color?

( ) Red
( ) Yellow
( ) Blue
Other, please specify:____________________

--------------

What is your favorite color?

( ) Yellow
( ) Red
( ) Blue
( ) Other, please specify:____________________


--------------

What is your favorite color?

( ) Blue
( ) Yellow
( ) Red
( ) Other, please specify:____________________
```

I have a code that works, but I can't keep the last option still...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Semi-Random Checkboxes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <fieldset id="checkboxes" data-role="controlgroup">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="yellow">Yellow</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Other">Other, specify</label><input type="text" value="text">
  </fieldset>

  <script>
    (function($) {
      var container = $("#checkboxes");
      var cbs = container.children("label");
      var index;
      for (index = 0; index < cbs.length; ++index) {
          $(cbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * cbs.length)]).appendTo(container);
      }
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Fisher Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) - use this algorithm, but just leave the last one alone, or simply append it after the others have been shuffled.

Comment: IT'S NOT COOL TO TYPE IN ALL CAPS, SUCH AS IN THE QUESTION'S TITLE.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT YOUR QUESTIONS. It makes them harder to read, it's annoying, and SHOUTING at people you're asking for free help is simply rude. The Shift key was added to the keyboard for a reason. Typing in all CAPS won't get you help any faster. Please don't do it. Thanks.